# Whats the best way to do `setTimeout` or `setInterval` with FAAS?

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions

Using serverless [Functions As A Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_as_a_service) (AWS Lambda, GCP Functions), what is the best way to run a timer or interval for sometime in the future?

I do not want to keep the instance running idle whilst the timer counts down. The timer will be less than 24 hrs, and needs to change dynamically at runtime (it isn't a single set up cron schedule).

Google has Cloud Scheduler, but that mimics cron and will not let me have a timer for any amount of seconds starting from now.

Comment: "I do not want to keep the instance running idle whilst the timer counts down." - then use a `cron` job or use a service that sends a HTTP trigger request to your service. If you want to maintain JavaScript state (such as in a closure over `setTimeout`/`setInterval` then you need to keep the instance running - that's how JavaScript works.

Comment: probably a timer should never be used

Comment: @Dai - There will be no closure state - just an ID that can be serialised into a HTTP POST body.

Comment: So u just skip over my comment on a timer never being used @zino. I guess at your current approach you need a timer. Can i ask humbly sir, for what purpose?

Comment: @GetSet Time is one of the 4 dimensions of spacetime. Our computers are running alongside us humans in the physical world; time is a key dimension. Your program cannot exist without time.

Comment: More concretely I need to run a function at a certain time in the future, but if all my instances are shut down there will be nothing to trigger that event. So some external system with a timer is needed. Most programming languages have functions in their standard libraries for timing, but FAAS removes the assumption a process will be running for a long time.

Comment: Physics aside @zino, `So some external system with a timer is needed.` is the ideal if not only sensible approach

Comment: And to be nerd, existence did exist before time. Which explains why time is "variable". In computers however, despite nano variations of keeping track of time, i dont really correlate your mention of it

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a product that's similar to Cloud Scheduler, but lets you schedule a single function invocation for an arbitrary amount of time in the future, you should look at [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks).  You have to [create a queue](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-queues), then arrange for it to [create an HTTP target](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks) to run at some time in the future.

Comment: This looks useful - can I a) set a recurring interval timer or b) cancel a task that has already been placed into the queue for a time a in the future?

Comment: a) no, b ) yes.  I suggest reading through the documentation thoroughly to understand what all it can do. https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs